# Symbolic break on a certain message type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I would like to break on any isEqualToString: message sent. The issue is that this message is being sent to an NSNull, however it's not showing the line where it's breaking.

Suggestions?

Comment: some code would help in solving your issue

Comment: Are you sure you have this right? Is it being sent to NSNull or to nil?

Comment: it's being sent to NSNull. nil wouldn't cause a crash. I actually have found a fun way to identify the issue and will be posting the solution shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symbolic breakpoint and point it to the Super Most Class...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can only break on methods, not messages. But you can get around this one pretty easily:

```
@interface NSNull (StringEqualityForDebugging)
    - (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)string;
@end

@implementation NSNull (StringEqualityForDebugging)
    - (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)string { // <-- Breakpoint!
        NSLog(@"Execution won't get here anyway, so whatever");
        return NO;
    }
@end
```